# Python Openpyxl: how to stop inference or override the cell data type

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an number of Excel workbooks which I need to extract the 'PeriodYear' from. This data is held in the 'Overview' worksheet in the cell 'H7'.

I've been recommended to use ***openpyxl*** to achieve this goal, however I'm having a problem with it trying to infer the cell data type based on the cell's value which is having some strange results.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(filename=<excel file name>, read_only=True, data_only=True)

sheet = workbook["Overview"]

print(sheet["H7"].value)
```

Some examples of cell value as viewable in the worksheet and the openpyxl output result below:

- '20' (prints 20)
- '2020' (prints 2020)
- '02' (prints 2)
- '19 / 20' (prints 0.95)

**Is there a way to force *openpyxl* to stop inferring the data type of a cell, or to override it to read cell values as a string instead?**

**Or is there a different way of achieving the same goal not using *openpyxl*?**

Comment: What is actually in cell H7? Select it, and hit "Ctrl-Shift-#". That should remove any "helpful" Excel formatting and show what datatype Excel is storing.

Comment: openpyxl only infers dates and datetimes. You probably want to look at the number format for the relevant cells.

Comment: @DS_London In the most annoy case (the '19 / 20' returning as 0.95) the cell is set to 'Custom' and if I change that to 'General' it actually says 0.95 as the value. This isn't the intended value however, it should be a string containing '19 / 20' as viewed in the sheet.

Comment: What happens if you put a ' (single quote) in front of 19 / 20?

Comment: @DS_London that works as expected, however I have over 100 files (used as a pro-forma by the business for contract changes) and I do not have the option to go into each sheet and change/correct them. I was looking for an option outside of excel for this at the point of reading the data from the file.

Comment: You say the format is "Custom" .. if you right-click on the cell, choose "Format cells " ... in the Number tab, does it say what format string is being applied? Also ... if your cell is H7, put the formula =H7 in another cell and see what you get? Just trying to narrow down whether it is an Excel issue, and nothing to do with openpyxl.

Comment: So ... if the value is really 0.95, but the cell has the number format string: "# ??/??" it will appear as 19/20

Comment: If, for example, you did your extraction using VBA, you could extract the Text() property of the cell, which would give you the string as displayed. Or, if you are dedicated to Python you could access Excel via the COM interface and "drive" Excel that way.

Comment: @DS_London yeah it seems when they originally entered the data the format set itself to be Custom 00/00, resulting in the cell actually containing 0.95 but being displayed as originally entered (19 / 20).. Thanks for your help DS_London, I think I'm going to have to go back to the business to request they sanitize their sheets a little before handing them over for processing.